# how to insert unique codes in a field with laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

my problem is that with a job (done in laravel 5.7) I need to change the codes of some promotions every day, the problem with the code that I have made changes the promotion code but it is the same for everyone, and I need it different for each of the promotions.
my code

```
DB::table('promociones')->update(['codigo_promocion'=>str_random(4)]);
```

Comment: Then you need some sort of WHERE clause added to the update so you only update the specific rows you want updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a lot of data like thousands of rows to update you can use a loop for it.

Using Eloquent:

```
$promociones = Promociones::all();

foreach($promociones as $promocion) {
   $promocion->codigo_promocion = $this->generateUniqueString();
   $promocion->save();
}
```

or by using query builder:

```
$promociones = DB::table('promociones')->get();

forea ch($promociones as $promocion) {
   DB::table('promociones')
     ->where('id', $promocion->id)
     ->update(['codigo_promocion'=> $this->generateUniqueString()]);
}
```

And the `generateUniqueString` should check if the string is already inserted in the database:

```
private function generateUniqueString()
{
   while(true) {
     $randomString = str_random(4);
     $doesCodeExist = DB::table('promociones')
       ->where('codigo_promocion', $randomString)
       ->count();

     if (! $doesCodeExist) {
        return $randomString;
     }
   }
}
```

Use `where()` if you need to filter the data.
Keep in mind if you have a lot of data you should consider using an approach like `queues` for example.

Comment: there won't be thousands of data ... thank you very much it worked.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to handle this would be looping:

```
$promotions = Promocione::where(...)->get(); 
// Note, replace `...` with logic to target specific codes that need to be changed today.

foreach($promotions AS $promotion){
  $promotion->codigo_promocion = str_random(4);
  $promotion->save();
}
```

This assumes you have a `Promocione` model, and can be very performance intensive depending on the number of records in the database. Also, `str_random(4)` doesn't guaranteed a random value (in comparison to other uses of `str_random(4)` in the same loop), nor does it provide a large pool of random values, so you'll likely end up with duplicates. You can query for existing duplicates while looping, and generate a new code if you find one, but as you exhaust your pool of `str_random(4)` codes, this process will "lock up" to the eventually point of infinite execution.